# Gmaps4Rails and geocoder : way to keep the request client side to avid Heroku blocking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, client-side, gmaps4rails, google-geocoder

I have successfully implemented geocoder and Gmaps4Rails in my Rails 4 app with the custom design i was looking for. The issue is that the way Geocoder is used under RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=comments seems to be incompatible with a normal Heroku set up and far from being optimize.

My map displays places for people, and everyone can create its own map with their best addresses.

Right now I geocode the place with the geocoder gem, and use then the latitude and longitude to build the markers.

Is there a way to keep only the address column in my Place Model and to build the markers client side everytime a client opens a map ? And if so how to switch from Geocoder to that JavaScript map creation and why Gmaps4rails and Geocoder aren't oriented that way but server side as far as I understand ?

My code is rather ordinary now:

MODEL

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
```

CONTROLLER

```
def show
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@diary.places) do |place, marker|
    marker.lat place.latitude
    marker.lng place.longitude
    marker.json({ title: place.title, id: place.id, category: place.category })
    marker.picture({
          :url    => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(place.category.split(" ").first + ".png"),
          :width  => 24,
          :height => 24
         })
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/diaries/map/map_box", locals: {place: place})
  end
end
```

VIEW

```
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- Contains all js linked to building the Google Map -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {styles: mapStyle}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){

    // set marker infos from gmaps4rails ruby @hash built in controller
    markers_json = <%= raw @hash.to_json %>;
    markers = _.map(markers_json, function(marker_json){
      marker = handler.addMarker(marker_json);
      _.extend(marker, marker_json);
      return marker;
    });

    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);

    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
})
</script>
```

Comment: Gmaps4rails is fully client side. But it needs coordinates :)